# Selecting text in textview from some start to some end

Tags: android, textview

I have an object which stores start and end of the selection made on the textview earlier. I do it by `textview.getSelectionStart()` and `textview.getSelectionEnd()`.
Now I am in another activity and I have this object and the same textview, I need to programmatically select the text again in order to edit the selection.(I have start and end of the previous selection).
Please help!